# How to close Bootstrap modal window after set interval of time using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a script which makes AJAX calls to update a page every 5 seconds. I want to display a alert/popup every time a change is observed i.e. for the first time when the page loads, I want to display a popup that says "Everything setup!" and on the subsequent page loads via AJAX, I'll display a popup IF there is any change. The popup stays on the page for 2 seconds and then disappears.

I am able to make the AJAX calls successfully. However, the popup window does not work as expected.

**Observed behavior :-** The popup window shows up on page load as expected, but it does not close after 2 seconds. However, the page refreshes after 5 seconds due to AJAX call. The popup remains in its place unless I manually close it.

I think I have figured out where the problem may be arising. The AJAX calls are being made through the `setInterval()` function of JS. I had removed that statement and tried calling the popup function and it worked as expected i.e. the page loaded and then the popup appeared. After 2 seconds the popup closed automatically. This method however is not helpful as I will not be able to perform the page reloads in the background after every 5 seconds.

The issue seems to arise from the AJAX calls.

HTML - `dashboard.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id='modal-disp' class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      No new images!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image-area">





<div class="container dash-container main-body" >

    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <br>
        <hr >
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="jumbotron ">
                <h1 id="hdr">DASHBOARD</h1>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    {% if folders %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 folder-list" id="info">

            Please select the Date to view their corresponding test results.<br><br>
            {% set ns = namespace(counter=0) %}
            <table class="table table-hover ">
                {% for row in range(rows) %}
                <tr class="row-hover">
                    {% for data in range(3) %}
                        {% if ns.counter  < folders|length %}
                            <td>
                                <a class="folder-link" href="{{ url_for('image',im=folders[ns.counter]) }}">{{  folders[ns.counter]  }}</a>
                                <br>
                                {% set ns.counter = ns.counter + 1 %}
                            </td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}



{% if images %}

<div class="row" id="info">

    <a href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="info">
            {% set ns = namespace(counter=0) %}
            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered images-table" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                {% for row in range(rows) %}
                <tr class="image-hover">
                    {% for data in range(3) %}
                        {% if ns.counter  < images|length %}
                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="{{ url_for('display',file=images[ns.counter][10:],folder=images[ns.counter][0:10]) }}"><img src="{{ url_for('static',filename=images[ns.counter]) }}" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>
                                {% set ns.counter = ns.counter + 1 %}
                            </td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endif %}

</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Javascript file -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var first_time = 0;
    var current_count = 0;
    var total_count = 0;

    function update(){
        $('#modal-disp').modal('show');
         setTimeout(function() { $("#modal-disp").modal('hide'); }, 2000);

            if (first_time === 0){
                current_count = $('td').length;
                total_count = current_count;
                first_time = 1;
                //var txt = $("<p class='notify'></p>").text("No new images");



                $('body').append("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-12'><p class='notify'><br>Up to date !</p></div></div>");
                $('.notify').css({'color':'#06661f','font-size':'30px','font-family': "'Saira',sans-serif",'font-style':'bold','text-align': 'center'});
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');

                //$('#myModal').modal('hide');
                setTimeout(function() { $(".notify").text(""); }, 5000);


            }
            else {

                total_count = $('td').length;
                if (total_count>current_count){
                    $('.notify').text(total_count-current_count + " new image added !");

                    $('.notify').css({'color':'#bc0041','font-size':'30px','font-family': "'Saira',sans-serif",'font-style':'bold','text-align': 'center' });
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
                    //alert(total_count-current_count + ' images added !');
                    current_count = total_count;
                    setTimeout(function() { $(".notify").text(""); }, 5000);

                }
            }

    }
        //setInterval(function(){ $('.image-area').load("{{ url_for('image',im=image_date) }}"); update(); }, 2000);


        setInterval(function(){$('.image-area').load("{{ url_for('image',im=image_date) }}", function() {update();}); }, 5000);

</script>
```

Here, Flask is used in the back end. So I am calling the `/image` route every 5 seconds. For the sake of keeping the code simple, I am just displaying a static popup for now. The popup is defined at the top of the HTML file. My best guess is the AJAX calls are interfering with the DOM and as a result the modal ID tag is getting masked.

Please help.

---

**EDIT 1:**

Notice in Image 1, there is the popup and also the message - "Up to date!" at the extreme bottom of the page. This works as it should because the page is loaded for the first time.

[image: image 1]

Here, in image 2 you can see that the message -"Up to date" is not there anymore. This behavior is also expected because according to code logic, the message is displayed on initial page load only. It will not be displayed on subsequent AJAX page reloads. Check the function update() for clarity.

At the same time, you can see that the alert box has remained in its place. More than 10 seconds have passed and the alert box has not closed at all.

[image: image 2]

---

**EDIT 2:**

I have noticed that if I place the HTML for the modal inside the div tag with class="image-area", the popup closes after 2 seconds but its backdrop (i.e the grayed out background ) does not disappear. Also, because of this, the entire website becomes unresponsive. Clicking anywhere, on the screen has no effect and everything appears grayed out due to the presence of the backdrop.

The div with class area="image-area" defined at the top encloses all the HTML that is refreshed every 5 seconds. This part of the HTML is fetched from the back end.

Python - routes.py

```
@app.route('/image/<im>')
@login_required
def image(im):
    image_src=[im+'/'+i for i in  os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder,im))]
    rows=math.ceil(len(image_src)/3)
    print(image_src)
    return render_template('dashboard.html',title='Welcome',images=image_src,rows=rows,image_date=im)
```

The above behavior is observed when I move the modal HTML inside the topmost div tag as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}


<div class="image-area">


<div id='modal-disp' class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      No new images!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container dash-container main-body" >

    <hr>
```

The following image shows the web page after the popup disappears. Note, clicking anywhere in the web page does not yield any response.

[image]